# Azure query list not working

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
var tableQuery = await MobileService.GetTable<Table>().Where(item => item.Id == rowId).ToEnumerableAsync();



cN = tableQuery;

    List<Table> asList = cN.ToList();



    foreach(var item in asList)
        {

        Debug.WriteLine(item.Text);

            if(item.ToString() != keyEntry.Text){



                ckIndex++;

            }


        }
```

It is meant to query a specific row in my azure table (specified by the id) and list each item, however when I run debug.writeline to see the data it just prints out a blank. Am I doing something wrong with converting to a list?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint and step through your code, what’s the content of tableQuery? Is anything returned?

Comment: @OlaEkdahl it's equal to {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.QueryResultEnumerable<MyApp.Table>}

Comment: Please make sure that there are  records in your query. You could get the count via `var count = asList.Count;`. It seems there is no issue in your mentioned code. You also could change the condition to query and check it.

Comment: @AppleGeek you can also use `.Where(item => item.Id == rowId).ToListAsync()` to return the list immediately instead of trying to defer the enumeration. While debugging the list will show how many records are within it. Chances are that the list is just empty as the query did not find any matches.